# When should you use ax. in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I still don't understand the best usage of fig, plt. and ax. in matplotlib 
Should I be using plt. all the time?
When should ax. be used?

Answer (score 1):

Use `fig` and `ax` are part of the [object oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pythonic_matplotlib.html) and should be used as often as possible.

Using the old `plt` interface works in most cases too, but when you create and manipulate many figures or axes it can become quite tricky to keep track of all your figures:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(...)      # this implicitly modifies the axis created beforehand
plt.xlim([0, 10])  # this implicitly modifies the axis created beforehand
plt.show()
```

compared to

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(...)           # this explicitly modifies the axis created beforehand
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])   # this explicitly modifies the axis created beforehand
plt.show()
```