# Pandas plot bar: legends of other columns appears in plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, legend

I have the following code and run it on jupyter.

```
# Make the 4 plots:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Dwell Time
ax = hour_17['Average Dwell Time'].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 10), 
legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("5-minutes interval between 17:00-18:00", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Time (sec)", fontsize=12)
plt.savefig('name1.jpeg')

# Waiting Time
ax = hour_17['Average Waiting Time'].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 10), 
legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("5-minutes interval between 17:00-18:00", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Time (sec)", fontsize=12)
plt.savefig('name2.jpeg')
```

There the following problems regarding it:
The first plot displays the indicated column and legend, while the second plot contains two legend: Average Waiting time and Average Dwell Time and displays the same information as the first plot.
In reality I have to plot data from 4 columns, so the last plot contains 4 legends.

Any idea of what is going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing in your code is storing the plot data for both plots to `ax`, hence the extra legend. Ideally, you want to use the `plt.subplots()` coding style to prevent this. You have two options:

1. Rename ax to something else (perhaps ax2) for waiting time.
2. Initialize a separate plot using plt.subplots()

The third option is to not use the fig, ax style at all, but to use the plt.plot method directly. There is a lot of discussion about why this is a bad idea. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152940/when-should-you-use-ax-in-matplotlib) explains the difference in methods.

If you want to do two separate plots use the single plot method below, just twice. If you want to combine the plots you can use the second method. This is from the matplotlib documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html).

```
#Creates just a figure and only one subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('Simple plot')

#Creates two subplots and unpacks the output array immediately
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing Y axis')
ax2.scatter(x, y)
```

Comment: Perhaps mark the solution? That way others can find it if they have a similar solution. I'm glad it worked!

Comment: I am new user and don't have the permission to mark!